# Check multiple columns from one table against one column in another table

Tags: sql, sql-server, t-sql

I have two tables on SQL Server.

First:

`[id] ... [name1] ... [name2] [name3] ... [name4] ... [name5] [name6]`

Second:

`[id] ... [name] ...`

I would like to select all rows from the first table, where all the names exists in the second table. I know there is a way to do this with 6 joins, but is there any "prettier" way?

```
SELECT A.*
FROM FirstTable A
    LEFT JOIN SecondTable B ON A.[Name1] = B.[Name]
    LEFT JOIN SecondTable C ON A.[Name2] = C.[Name]
    ...
WHERE
    B.[Name] IS NOT NULL
    AND C.[Name] IS NOT NULL
    ...
```

Bonus question, is there a way to instead selecting only the rows that contain valid names, to select all of them and add another column to the select, which would point out which of the names are invalid?

Comment: The WHERE conditions make your LEFT JOINs return regular INNER JOIN result.

Comment: Show us some sample table data and the expected result - all as formatted text, not images. ([mcve])

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use `apply`:

```
select t1.*
from table1 t1 cross apply
     (select count(*) as cnt
      from (values (name1), (name2), (name3), (name4), (name5), (name6)
           ) v(name) join
           table2 t2
           on t2.name = v.name
     ) v
where v.cnt = 6;
```

Your method can be marginally simplified by replacing the `LEFT JOIN`s with `INNER JOIN`s and removing the `WHERE` clause.  The `INNER JOIN`s require a match.